# How do I Install Ubuntu 11 on a Dell Latitude E6400 with a Sata Hard Disk?

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 11, and after burning it to a DVD, i have been unable to install the OS, i even had to change my sata configuration to AHCI, or Advanced Host Controller Interface, reformat my Hard Disk, yet it wont install. Please what do i do?

Comment: you have to provide detilas

Comment: Ubuntu 11 what do you mean 11.10 OR 11.04

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in that I was merely going into the one time boot option of (F12)...after going into the BIOS and resetting the boot priority I was able to get Ubuntu to load right up on my Toshiba laptop.  Have you tried changing the boot priority?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is weird.Ubuntu will install in SATA configuration itself.Moreover you should provide more details.If you are able run Ubuntu live from CD or DVD, use the disk utility to check your hard disk's state.